# Where are the options in the JavaScript code for BootStrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Looking through the official BootStrap JS file, I found this code:

```
var Modal = function (element, options) {
  this.options             = options
  this.$body               = $(document.body)
  this.$element            = $(element)
  this.$dialog             = this.$element.find('.modal-dialog')
  this.$backdrop           = null
  this.isShown             = null
  this.originalBodyPad     = null
  this.scrollbarWidth      = 0
  this.ignoreBackdropClick = false

  if (this.options.remote) {
    this.$element
      .find('.modal-content')
      .load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function () {
        this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal')
      }, this))
  }
}

Modal.prototype.escape = function () {
  if (this.isShown && this.options.keyboard) {
    this.$element.on('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
      e.which == 27 && this.hide()
    }, this))
  } else if (!this.isShown) {
    this.$element.off('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal')
  }
}
```

It looks like the code uses `this.options` a lot of times to check some options. (I Guess?) The code also appears to set these options in the second line `this.options = options`. What I don't understand is where are these options provided to the Modal and what are the different values provided to it?

Comment: It's all explained here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

Comment: Thanks @ZimSystem. I never noticed them before. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options can be passed via HTML `data` attributes or JavaScript. For `data` attributes, append the option name to `data-`, as in `data-backdrop=""`.
See table below:

**backdrop**   `boolean` or the string `static` - Includes a modal-backdrop element. Alternatively, specify static for a backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click.

**keyboard**   `boolean` - Closes the modal when escape key is pressed

**show**   `boolean` - Shows the modal when initialized.

**remote** `path` - This option is deprecated since v3.3.0 and has been removed in v4

Comment: Thanks bodi0. If I don't specify any of these options, do they default to `true`?

Comment: All of them by default are set to `true`, except for `remote`

Comment: One more question. Is the value of `remote` equal to the `href` attribute if not specified explicitly? Thanks.